# How to set up a nodejs application server in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I don't understand why i have this problem which i show the output in the second part. While following the tutorial "how To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 14.04" i did everything.

I created a script to test my private ip address like this

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'myPrivateIp');
console.log('Server running at http://myPrivateIp:8080/');
```

The problem that i encountered while testing the apllication.

```
JoeDoe@myUbuntu:~$ node hello.js
Server running at http://myPrivateIp:8080/
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL myPrivateIp:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1218:19)
    at listen (net.js:1267:10)
    at net.js:1376:9
    at doNTCallback3 (node.js:440:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:477:11)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `listen` is not the domain name, is the address to listen on. It could be something like `192.168.x.x` or `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` ( means all address. ). The default is `127.0.0.1`.

Which means you should remove the second argument of `listen`.

Comment: Thanks, i figure out that i am doing the web server and app server in a single server!